# Attaching click handler to canvas element with jquery

Tags: jquery, canvas, click

I am trying to make 4 buttons in a canvas, but I can't seem to get the attached. In order to test that the button itself is working I am simply setting the "score" and then redrawing the canvas to show the new score, but this isn't working. An example button is as such:

```
var blueButton = new Object();
blueButton.x = w/2;
blueButton.y = h/3+30;
blueButton.width = w/2-10;
blueButton.height = h/3;
blueButton.color = "blue";
```

The jquery used to created the click handler is like this:

```
//setup the click handler for the elements on the canvas
$("#canvas")[0].click(function(eventObject){
    mouseX = eventObject.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = eventObject.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    if(isInButton(greenButton, mouseX, mouseY)){
        score = 0;
        drawGameBoard();
    } else if(isInButton(redButton, mouseX, mouseY)){
        score = 1;
        drawGameBoard();
    } else if(isInButton(yellowButton, mouseX, mouseY)){
        score = 2;
        drawGameBoard();
    } else if(isInButton(blueButton, mouseX, mouseY)){
        score = 3;
        drawGameBoard();
    }
})
```

and the javascript to detect if a click is in the button is here:

```
function isInButton(buttonObj, mouseX, mouseY){
    if(((mouseX > buttonObj.x) && (mouseX < (buttonObj.x + buttonObj.width))) && ((mouseY > buttonObj.y) && (mouseY < (buttonObj.y + buttonObj.height))))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Can anyone see why my clicks would not be registering?

EDIT: Here is the markup. I don't believe getting the canvas element without [0] works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Simon Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Simon </h1>
    <p> This is the simple memory game simon.<br>Mimic the pattern the computer creates until you can't remember what is next.</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And this is inside the `ready`? Ermmm Actually, why do you have `$("#canvas")[0]`? Do you have a bunch of elements with the same ID? Please post your markup as well.

Comment: yeah it is all in the ready function of the document (which is setup correctly). I think you need the [0] as it doesn't work without it.

Answer (score 4):

After researching this problem for a good hour I finally understood it.

```
    $("#canvas")[0].whateverfollowsthis
```

returns the actual DOM element. That means that the variable created from it can't actually be used with jquery functions such as .click and .offset.

```
 $("#canvas").whateverfollowsthis
```

allows you to work with jquery functions.

The proper code is as follows:

```
$("#canvas").click(function(e){
    mouseX = e.pageX - $("#canvas").offset().left;
    mouseY = e.pageY - $("#canvas").offset().top;

    if(isInButton(greenButton, mouseX, mouseY)){
        score = 0;
        clickTile(0);
    } else if(isInButton(redButton, mouseX, mouseY)){
        score = 1;
        clickTile(1);
    } else if(isInButton(yellowButton, mouseX, mouseY)){
        score = 2;
        clickTile(2);
    } else if(isInButton(blueButton, mouseX, mouseY)){
        score = 3;
        clickTile(3);
    }
})
```